# How do i hide the controls beside the Play button in React-player?

Tags: reactjs, react-player

So i've been trying to hide the controls beside the Play button but with no luck. Does anyone know how I can do this? Also, I would like the controls to appear after "play" has been clicked.

Currently my code simply looks like this:

```
<div>
                <ReactPlayer
                  classNameName="btn-modal object-cover"
                  url="Assets/video/stephanie.mp4"
                  type="video/mp4"
                  controls
                  width="270px"
                  
                />
              </div>
```

Comment: I am also having the same issue, did you get a answer for this